# My `addToCart` function is not showing any result

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the code where I have my `addtocart` function,

```
import React from 'react'
import './Body.css'
import { useState } from 'react'
// import './Cart.js'
export default function Pricetag(props) {

  const [count, setCartCount] = useState(0)
  return (
    <div>

      <div className="cart">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>
        <div id="number">=</div>
      </div>

      <div className="card1">

        <div className="image">
          <img src={props.images} alt="" className='card-image' />
        </div>

        <div className="content">

          <div className="name">
            {props.name}
          </div>

        </div>

        <div className="button">
          <button className='btn no1' id='cartbutton' onClick={() => setCartCount( count +1)} >
            {/* <a id="cart" href="https://wa.me/<919650988301>" target='_blank' rel="noreferrer" className='no1'>Add to cart</a></button> */}
            Add to cart </button>
        </div>

      </div>

      <script ></script>

    </div>
  )
}
```

When I do,

```
number.innerHTML+=`${items}`
```

instead of

```
number.innerHTML=`${items}`
```

then the numbers are concatenated like strings.
Otherwise, nothing is happening, what is wrong here?
Can you suggest me some edits in the same code.

Comment: When you use ${} you are transforming the value to string so ``items`` is a string

Comment: Yes, but without += the number is not updating

Comment: try without the ${} ``number.innerHTML= Number(number.innerHTML) + items``

Comment: I tried not working

Comment: where are you calling the addCart function from? can you add the code where it is called pls? :)

Comment: Sorry my comment got updated too late, you can do
```number.innerHTML= Number(number.innerHTML) + items```

Comment: Miguel Hidalgo I am getting NaN now

Answer (score 2):

As you are using React framework you should use [React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Here is an example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './Body.css'
// import './Cart.js'
export default function Pricetag(props) {


  const  [cartCount, setCartCount] = useState(0)


  return (
    <div>

      <div className="cart">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>
        <div id="number">={cartCount}</div>
      </div>

      <div className="card1">

        <div className="image">
          <img src={props.images} alt="" className='card-image' />
        </div>

        <div className="content">

          <div className="name">
            {props.name}
          </div>

        </div>

        <div className="button">
          <button className='btn no1' id='cartbutton' onClick={() => setCartCount(cartCount +1))} >
            {/* <a id="cart" href="https://wa.me/<919650988301>" target='_blank' rel="noreferrer" className='no1'>Add to cart</a></button> */}
            Add to cart </button>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  )
}
```

Working on codesandbox

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks I forgot to add innerHTML line... I have one more question why it was not  working without hooks

Comment: when I am running the same code then initially there is zero but as I add to the cart the new number overlaps over the existing zero why is this happening